# "OHS supervision log" meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I got a document related to construction working and among various staff I got this term.
There were some safety measures and health certificates stuff related.

I've found that OHS stands for Occupational Health and Safety.
But I am not sure does that meaning of the term above.
I suspect that means all certificates for working in required conditions.

Comment: Have you also looked up *supervision* and *log*?

Comment: I got forwarded email to translated it. 
It seems that is some health related certificates for working on the site.
And sometimes I am not sure if it is broken English or some things I don't understand.

Comment: A *log* is a record containing entries for significant events. I would guess that this is a log made by the OHS supervisor.  I don't see how it could be certificates. I would further guess that the log contains either entries relating to inspection results or entries relating to OHS rule violations or infractions or maybe both.

Comment: I know that there is construction log, but I haven't heard of OH & S log. I will translate that log made by OHS supervisor. Could you copy your second comment into the answer so you receive magic internet points?

Comment: Internet points aren't worth the paper they're printed on. And besides, the fun is in the answering, not the points. We are glad that you got some enlightenment. Don't be disappointed if he doesn't come back and re-post his comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your use of the word "staff" is an error and you mean "stuff" but your question still doesn't quite make sense to me! What do you mean by "But I am not sure does that meaning of the term above?"

You are probably correct in assuming that OHS means OH&S i.e. Occupational Health and Safety" but the certificates and safety measures need to be read in context.

I strongly suggest that you ask the sender or your supervisor to clarify this for you. OH&S is a very serious matter in the workplace, and if you make a mistake in interpreting this document there is the possibility you might make yourself liable for any accidents which happen on your watch!